# How to Use Textinputaction.next and Textinputaction.done at a same time

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm working on a project which required the Next and Done buttons on the keyboard at the same time. Anyone can help me with how to use the Next and done button at the same time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**TextInputAction.next** and **TextInputAction.done** not possible at same time.

But you can create your own keyboard where you can add toolbar buttons. You can check this pub to add shortcuts above keyboard: https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions